# Correct method of checking with an array has elements

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am trying to check a returned array exists before accessing its elements. At first I had

```
$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($img_id, 'type')[0];
```

But since the array didn't exist, I changed this to

```
$check = wp_get_attachment_image_src($img_id, 'type');
if ($check) {
    $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($img_id, 'type')[0];
}
```

Despite this check (which is the same as the wordpress recommendation below) I still get the error within the `if` statement

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Here is the wordpress example usage below. I cannot see why mine is different. I have tried `!empty($check)` and a number of other things. What silly mistake am I making?

```
<?php 
$attachment_id = 8; // attachment ID

$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id ); // returns an array
if( $image_attributes ) {
?> 
<img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image_attributes[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image_attributes[2]; ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to `var_dump()` the `wp_get_attachment_image_src($img_id, 'type')[0];`? Since I'm pretty sure it's not an array. And since it's syntax error, maybe you just have outdated PHP version and need to call later `$img = $img[0]`.

Comment: Use `is_array()`: `if (is_array($check))) { $img = $check[0]; }` or `isset`: `if (isset($check[0]))) { $img = $check[0]; }`.

Comment: remove the [0] and after that you can do $img = $img[0];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't append [] at the end of function calls for php version below 5.4. you first need to assign a variable to the function result.

```
$check = wp_get_attachment_image_src($img_id, 'type');
if ($check) {
    $img = $check[0];
}
```

Comment: You _can_ do that since PHP version 5.4.

Comment: Actually you can append `[]` after function call, but only if function returns array and you use newer PHP (not sure whats minimum version)

Comment: @MarcellFülöp - Thanks! My local PHP version is newer than the server im deploying to, never would have figured that out!

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this ?

```
if (count($your_array) > 0)
{
    ...
}
```